VS Code editor - not running, not able to re-install, auto-update failed
I am having problems with my code editor- VS CODE (visual studio code)
I was practicing some code and working with api's, enjoying my time. When I closed it I got a prompt message that auto-update failed...
Later my VS Code editor stopped opening, even the logo turned into a blank page. Error messages like: broken file path, access denied...
My windows screen defender gave a warning that it can put my device to risk. I tried to click 'run anyway' but error popped up and it failed...
I have tried opening it multiple times, tried to click 'run anyway' in the error message, still failed.
I tried updating it but that also didnt work...
I also downloaded the installation setup to re-download VS Code editor but my windows screen defender gives me the error about the risk. The 'run anyway' option also not working.
This problem is since a week now...
Device- Windows 11
Why does this happen? Is there a safe and secure way to solve the issue..?

Try to reinstall again by completely unistalling.

Well, that was simple... Thank You! BUT what was the cause...?
